# Can't load Chartis js in an Aurelia project

Tags: aurelia, amd, chartist.js

I have been unsuccessful trying to add chartis.js to even a brand new aurelia project. I tried with two different projects created with the aurelia cli. In the first project I tried adding chartis by itself through npm. The second project I tried installing the aurelia-chartis plugin using npm. I followed the aurelia plugin guide to the letter and still nothing.

It seems that in both of my projects the actual chartis.js script IS being added to the vendor-bundle.js, but the script is never actually being executed.

Specifically, in the vendor bundle, I see this code:

```
define('Chartist', [], function () {
  return (root['Chartist'] = factory());
});
```

Where factory() is the actual script. I put a breakpoint in that line, and ran root['Chartist'] = factory() myself, and confirmed that the global 'Chartist' variable was correctly created. So in essence, my problem is that the script is included but not executed.

Your help is greatly appreciated as it has been a few days and the frustration is really kicking in.

Comment: How is the section in your aurelia.json looking? Is it looking like the top part here https://github.com/eriklieben/aurelia-chartist#aurelia-cli?

Comment: this is a problem with chartist, they added 'Chartist' to define() since version 0.1 I believe, there's already an issue on github, in the meantime you can just delete the string 'Chartist' : define([], function () {

Comment: Erik, my aurelia.json looks just like that, at least for the project I made using the aurelia-chartist plug in.

Comment: Rabah, I saw one open issue where two people say that change caused it to break for them. But I also saw a closed issue where someone was asking for that specific change to be made (adding 'Chartist' to define) and when the change was made they said it worked for them. Im confused as to how define works. Isn't the first parameter the name of your module, and the second parameter the array of dependencies? So isn't it correct that 'Chartist' is the first parameter?

Comment: Just installed it in a project created with the cli version 0.25.0 (not sure if that will matter). There is a small bug. Will fix this when I am back home, what you can do for now is in node_modules\aurelia-chartist\dist\amd\chartist.js on line 10 change "chartist" to "Chartist" then it will work agian. Well at least, that made it working in my quick check

Comment: I think I'm not supposed to comment just to say "thank you", but thank you! That did fix my issue! If you submit that as an answer I'll make sure to mark it.

Comment: Anyone care to explain what the solution is? I'm facing the same issue with Aurelia CLI 0.29.0 and Chartist 0.11.0. `import Chartist from 'chartist';` is `undefined` regardless of how my `aurelia.json` looks.

Comment: Hi powerbuoy. Erik commented on what the solution is: "in node_modules\aurelia-chartist\dist\amd\chartist.js on line 10 change 'chartist' to 'Chartist'". It seems that the module loader was having some issues finding the correct thing because of case sensitivity. I dont know if the latest version of aurelia-chartist includes this fix, but if it doesn't then you can make the change yourself. Hopefully that fixes it for you.

Comment: please consider answering yourself and marking the question as answered